# Unit test proxyManager

Tags: java, proxy, mockito, bucket, bucket4j

I need to unit test this code, but i have been seeing null pointer exceptions at buckets.builder().

```
import io.github.bucket4j.distributed.proxy.ProxyManager;


private ProxyManager buckets;

 public Bucket resolveBucket(String key) {
    Supplier<BucketConfiguration> configSupplier = getConfigSupplierForUser();
    return buckets.builder().build(key, configSupplier);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @lesiak the question here is builder method is of the type abstract , that method is throwing NPE. do i have to mock it ?

Comment: Please post full stack trace

Comment: What value does `builder` have? It is a mock? What value does `builder()` return? (but very likely everything is already answered in the link posted by Lesiak "what is a NPE and how to fix")

Answer (score 0):

**buckets** is null, because you did not set any value to this field. You need to initialize this field before calling any method.

Comment: I tried mocking buckets.builder first and then buckets.builder.build () that helped me to get the unit test working. I have a proxy manager bean initialized by JcacheProxyManager. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried mocking buckets.builder first and then buckets.builder.build () that helped me to get the unit test to work. I have a proxy manager bean initialized by JcacheProxyManager.

```
 @InjectMocks private RateLimitingService rateLimitingService;

  @Mock RemoteBucketBuilder<String> remoteBucketBuilder;

  @Mock ProxyManager<String> buckets;

  @Test
  void shouldGetBucketsForThePassedKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

when(buckets.builder()).thenReturn(remoteBucketBuilder);
when(remoteBucketBuilder.build(
        anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Supplier<BucketConfiguration>>any()))
    .thenReturn(mock(BucketProxy.class));
Bucket bucket = rateLimitingService.resolveBucket("1", "1", "1");
assertNotNull(bucket);
```

}